# Enable JMX port for Cassandra 2

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I need to configure JMX on Casandra 2. I configured the configuration file this way:

/etc/cassandra/default.conf/cassandra-env.sh

```
........
    LOCAL_JMX=no

    if [ "$LOCAL_JMX" = "yes" ]; then
      JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=$JMX_PORT -XX:+DisableExplicitGC"
    else
      JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT"
      JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT"
      JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
      JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.1.146"
      JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true"
      JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password"
    fi

    JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS $JVM_EXTRA_OPTS"


chmod 600 /etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password

File content:

monitorRole QED
controlRole R&D
cassandra cassandrapassword
```

But in log file I get:

```
/usr/sbin/cassandra: line 155: /var/run/cassandra/cassandra.pid: No such file or directory
Error: Password file not readable: /etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password
```

Can you give some idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Looks like owner/group permission problem. Could you try with `chmod 666`?

Comment: `chmod 666` will make your password readable to everyone. `chown cassandra /etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password` is better try.